# How to create unit tests easily in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, testing, junit

I want to create unit tests easily by just selecting method. Is there a tool in eclipse that does that. It should support templates. I should be able to create positive test as well as negative tests.

Comment: I think this eclipse plugin is what you want : [MoreUnit](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/moreunit)

Comment: Ctrl+1 and select Create new JUnit test.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use my plug-in to create tests easily:

1. highlight the method
2. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
3. it will create the unit test for it.

The plug-in is available [here](http://fast-code.sourceforge.net). Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems like a great plugin!  I'm just curious if you might know of something similar for C/C++ in Eclipse?

Comment: this plugin just doesn't work for me, saying: "This actually a JUnit test" in my class :) I wanted something simple and working.

Comment: Hi @fastcodejava can u plz help we are getting following errors:
while using update site:
Unable to read repository at http://sourceforge.net/projects/fast-code/files/update/content.xml.

while using jar:
no test profile available please go to junit preference to set the profile

Comment: Anything is standard eclipse?

Answer (score 201):

To create a test case template:

"New" -> "JUnit Test Case" -> Select "Class under test" -> Select "**Available methods**". I think the wizard is quite easy for you.

Comment: I think OP wanted to select the method and create the unit test. I have written a plug-in for that.

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for, the Netbeans function does exactly the same, and when using maven its good that it creates the testcase in the correct folder

Comment: @TheresaForster Which one you like? This answer or the one given by fastcodejava?

Comment: Note that "available methods" is on the next page of the wizard (in Eclipse 4 at least)

Comment: Shortcut keys to this is ALT+SHIFT+N -> select JUnit Test Case (or hit J 3 times)

Comment: Command + Option (Alt) + N is shortcut key for Mac

Comment: you can select the class under test before as it will be automatically filled

Answer (score 7):

Check out this discussion <s>[How to automatically generate junits?]</s>

If you are starting new and its a java application then [Spring ROO](http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/) looks very interesting too!

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -4):

Any unit test you could create by just pressing a button would not be worth anything.  How is the tool to know what parameters to pass your method and what to expect back?  Unless I'm misunderstanding your expectations.

*Close* to that is something like [FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.OneMinuteDescription), where you can set up tests, then separately you set up a wiki page with your test data, and it runs the tests with that data, publishing the results as red/greens.

If you would be happy to make test writing much faster, I would suggest [Mockito](http://mockito.org/), a mocking framework that lets you very easily mock the classes around the one you're testing, so there's less setup/teardown, and you know you're really testing that one class instead of a dependent of it.

Comment: No tool can write the unit test you intend to create, but the OP wanted to find the tool that will highlight the method and created stub test. You then have to fill the the test method body. the default tool that comes with eclipse does a pretty good job, but one cannot highlight a method and create the test. Also in the test is already there the default tool will not work.

Comment: First, even automatically generated tests can be useful. Sometimes you simply forget to check something obvious - e.g. null pointer check.

Second, I think the question is meant to how to pregenerate tests, which you will implement yourself. Something like if you need to check, if your method throws exception accordingly, tool may generate empty test method with @Test(expected=...) anotation automatically.