# Debug a method in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I wanted to know whether you could debug a single method call

Say there's a method called howMany(char c,String str). I want to call it with 'c',"Hello world" and debug it without having to go through every previous code until I reach it

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Junit testing.  This will allow you to call in a single method.

[How to create unit tests easily in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131897/how-to-create-unit-tests-easily-in-eclipse)