# @Test annotations on test classes (types) instead on each test method

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, junit-jupiter

Is there any `@Test`-related annotation in the JUnit Jupiter API that allows us to highlight the whole test class as a testing class?

Since each test method needs to be annotated with `@Test`, this would save some time when writing tests within test classes that do not include non-test methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, back in 2019 the JUnit team decided against a class-level `@Test` annotation:

> There are many ways to declare tests in Jupiter: `@Test`, `@TestFactory`, `@TestTemplate` (`@RepeatedTest`, `@ParameterizedTest`) -- we want them to be explicitly visible and not rely on a pattern that matches a method signature.

https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1761#issuecomment-466149986

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid there is not such annotation in JUnit.

Is it really time consuming to add @Test on each method?

Maybe you could use your IDE auto generate tools to generate test methods for you, see for example:

- IntelliJ:  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-tests.html
- Eclipse:   [How to create unit tests easily in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131897/how-to-create-unit-tests-easily-in-eclipse)